# How to fetch 'n' random values out of an array c++

Tags: python, c++, arrays, random

I would like to fetch `n` random values out of an array.
I can do it in Python using `x=random.sample(listName, numberOfValuesNeeded)`

```
[code]
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int MAX_Name=100;

    srand((unsigned)time( NULL));

    // Names
    string PsDisp[MAX_Name]={"Alberto", "Bruno", "Carlo", "Dario", "Elio", "Francesco", "Giovanni", "Luca", "Marco", "Nicola", "Oreste", "Pietro",   "Rino", "Sandro", "Tonino", "Valerio", "Vittorio"};


    for(int x=1; x<=6; x++)
    {
        random_shuffle(begin(PsDisp), end(PsDisp));

        cout << x << ": " << endl; // snomething missing before endl
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I want to print on the screen:

> 1: random name1
>   2: random name3 ...
>   6: random name6

Comment: Note that `std::random_shuffle` is not recommended, because its randomness may be very  poor. [`std::shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) with an appropriate PRNG is better.

Comment: Can the 1-6 contain repetitions? If not, just sort once and print the first 6. The way to access an element is just `dispNames[x]`. And make your loop condition start at 0: `for (int x=06; x<6; ++x) ...`.

Comment: This is a really inefficient (and unnecessarily destructive) way to do it in the first place—it would be like using `random.shuffle(n); return n[0]` instead of `return random.choice(n)` in Python.

Comment: Also, `random.sample` gives you samples _without replacement_, but your algorithm gives you samples _with_ replacement. If you want your code to work without replacement, you'd just shuffle once and pick the first 6 values from the result. (But again, don't use shuffle for sampling…)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) returns samples *without replacement*. That means you can't get the same element twice.

Your algorithm obviously doesn't do the same. If you reshuffle after getting each value, that's replacing the values. But there's an easy way to fix that: just shuffle once, outside the loop, instead of each time through the loop.

And that means the loop is dead-simple: you just want to print the first 6 numbers in the shuffled `dispNames`. So:

```
random_shuffle(begin(dispNames), end(dispNames));
for (int x=1; x<=6; x++) {
    cout << x << ": " << dispNames[x-1] << endl;
}
```

A few side notes:

- `random_shuffle` is deprecated. And so is `shuffle` with the default PRNG. There's a good reason for that; even when you don't care about cryptographic randomness or anything fancy, you still want to use a specific PRNG, and the new version of `shuffle`, just to portably get a uniform distribution.
- It's more normal to count from `0` to `<6` than from `1` to `<=6`. And that would mean you don't need the `x-1`.
- It would be even better to use an iterator instead of indexing; then the same code would work even if you replaced `dispNames` with some other randomly-accessible type instead of an array.

---

For picking 6 samples out of a list of 17, this is fine. (Well, it's fine as long as it's acceptable to destructively modify the array, which Python's `random.sample` doesn't do… but if that's a problem, it's not hard to replace this with a copying shuffle, or just a copy plus a destructive shuffle…)

But if your values get too much larger, you need to think about efficiency. Shuffling inherently takes O(N) time, because it has to shuffle most of the N values. But picking K values out of N shouldn't take that long. (And if you switch to a copying shuffle, you're also adding O(N) space, which isn't necessary either.)

I don't think there's an equivalent in the C++ stdlib, but that's OK; it's worth learning how to implement this yourself so you'll understand what it's doing. There are a few different choices: You can build it on top of a permutation generator (which C++ does have in the stdlib), or on top of a trivial linear congruential generator for the next prime bigger than the length of your list (throwing out values that are too large), or a partial Fisher-Yates shuffle instead of a complete one, or probably other things I haven't thought of. (And some that are dead-simple and dead-fast in specific situations, but not in general—e.g., just choosing with replacement and keeping track of previous picks works great if K is tiny, but it's horrible if K is a sizable chunk of N.)

Or, of course, you can [read the CPython source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/random.py#l280), which is a pretty good way to figure out how to write C++ code that will do exactly the same thing as Python.

Comment: this solved the problem with some changes in the code: DELETE this line const int MAX_Name=100; CHANGE this line string PsDisp[MAX_Name]= in string PsDisp[17]= and then using your solution. With string PsDisp[MAX_Name]= the program, often, prints empty lines for names

Answer (score 0):

If you're not concerned about repetitions you can generate 6 random indexes and print the corresponding values like so:

```
for(int x=1; x<=6; x++)
{
    cout << x << ": " << dispNames[rand() % MAX_Name] << endl;
}
```

Comment: - a million for `rand()` (and using `%` on it). [C++ has proper facilities for PRNGs for a while now.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random#Example). [See STL's presentation.](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)

Comment: @BoBTFish Thanks, I haven't had cause to use random generation in my own work for years. The premise would still stand wouldn't it? Just replace `rand` with the PRNG of your choice?

Comment: Pretty much, as long as this has the behaviour OP is after (not clear from the question).

Comment: Just replacing `rand` wouldn't help; using `%` will turn even a perfectly uniform distribution into a non-uniform one for no good reason.

Comment: Ah ok, looks like I've got to go and do some reading before I next have to implement any randomness in a program then

Comment: @Kvothe Good read: http://cpp.indi.frih.net/blog/2014/12/the-bell-has-tolled-for-rand/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a technique called [Reservoir Sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling). It only iterates once over the input and thus needs O(n). Here's your sample code with a working C++11 reservoir sampling:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>


template<class InputIt, class Generator>
std::vector<typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type> sample(InputIt first, InputIt last, size_t n, Generator& engine) {
    assert(distance(first, last) >= n);
    InputIt nth = next(first, n);
    std::vector<typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type> result{first, nth};
    size_t k=n+1;
    for (InputIt it = nth; it != last; ++it, ++k) {
        size_t r = std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t>{0, k}(engine);
        if (r<n)
            result[r] = *it;
    }
    return result;
}


using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string xs[] = {"Alberto", "Bruno", "Carlo", "Dario", "Elio", "Francesco", "Giovanni", "Luca", "Marco", "Nicola", "Oreste", "Pietro",   "Rino", "Sandro", "Tonino", "Valerio", "Vittorio"};

    mt19937 engine{random_device{}()};
    vector<string> ys = sample(begin(xs), end(xs), 5, engine);

    for (const string& s : ys)
        cout << s << endl;

    return 0;
}
```